# Sending Extra string from client to server in Server sent event

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

```
source = new EventSource("stream");
```

This is how I connect to server pushing streaming data, Now my scenario is to send an extra string while making the connection. how do I achieve this ?

I am sure that I dont find any details about this on articles in internet !!

Anyone help!

Answer (score 0):

Since SSE just use normal HTTP URLs, you should be able to just add GET arguments when you initiate the connection.

```
source = new EventSource("http://example.com/sse?arg=value");
```

On the server side you would look for the `'arg'` key in the params.

Comment: Might be. But I suppose eventsource object takes only URL as parameter.